# Golden Pothos Yellowing/Variegation? Possibly Mosaic Virus?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-care, leaves

I am wondering if anyone can help me to understand if my Golden Pothos is getting improper care or if it has the mosaic virus. I have moved it to a location with less direct sunlight, but everything else has been consistent. Image 1 and 2 show what the variegation looks like on the top of the leaves, image 3 shows it on the back, and how some of the leaves are secreting fluid (not sure if that is typically normal), and image 4 is what the leaves look like when they are weak enough to just fall off when I give a light tug.
[image: Image 4]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 1]

Comment: Good question and good illustrations; if could include current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient type & amount & frequency, previous & present hours of sunlight per day, previous & present hours of diffuse light per day, average daytime temperature, average night time temperature, size of container, the soil, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Is this a Neon Pothos? It doesn't look like a standard Golden Pothos to me.

Comment: What did the plant look like before it changed?